# How to access asmx service in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asmx

I have created an asp.net core application to create a web API. I have to create a service reference to an asmx service. But I don't see any provision to create an asmx service reference. Any reference to a documentation will be highly appreciated.

I'm trying all these from Visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

For calling ASMX Web Service from .net Core, I suggest you try [Visual Studio WCF Connected Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=erikcai-MSFT.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService), I suggest you refer the link below for more information.

## WCF Connected Service for .NET Core 1.0 and ASP.NET Core 1.0 is now available

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/26/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/

Comment: that was old link, try this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService

Comment: This is now part of VS 2017 and does not require installing any plugins. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide